# S3Fox for Amazon S3 is not creating an account

Tags: amazon-s3, firefox-addon

So I installed firefox add-on *S3Fox* to upload and manage files on Amazon S3. I clicked on the "Managed Accounts" button and entered my credentials there.

[image]

But it is continuously showing me the message:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
```

[image]

Can anyone suggest the solution? Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. The Amazon account was not activated. Once I used the activated account, it accepted it successfully.

Comment: It asked to wait 2 days. So I was just waiting. Thanks anyway, I have marked it.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this message myself. Couldn't create a folder. But my account has been active for many years now.

I had created a folder inside of a bucket which had a space in its name, e.g. "xx xx" I had also previous created a folder inside of that, "cf-5b" a while back. Today I wanted to create another folder in "xx xx" but it refused with the same error message.

I was thrown by the fact that there was already an older folder in there.

So I went up a couple levels. Created a folder that had a space in it "yy yy" and that worked, but if I went into that folder and tried to create any folders, it would not let me and I got the error that you got.

Something changed in the API's at some point? Or an S3Fox issue (0.6).